# Symfony2 Mongodb to persist object multiple times

Tags: mongodb, symfony

Trying to persist object in MongoDB. I am new to MongoDB and Symfony.

My code is below:

```
    $neo = new Neo();
    $dm = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();


    $jd = new JsonDecode();
    $neo_obj = $jd->decode($response->getBody(),"json");
    foreach($neo_obj->near_earth_objects as $date => $object) {
      $output->writeln("Date:".$date); 

      $neo->setDate($date);

      foreach($neo_obj->near_earth_objects as $object1) {
        foreach($object1 as $object2)
        {
          $output->writeln("Name:".$object2->name);

          $neo->setName($object2->name); 

          $output->writeln("neo_reference_id:".$object2->neo_reference_id);

          $neo->setNeoReferenceId($object2->neo_reference_id);

          $output->writeln("is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid:".$object2->is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid);

          $neo->setIsPotentiallyHazardousAsteroid($object2->is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid);

          foreach($object2->close_approach_data as $object3)
          {
            $i=0;
            foreach($object3->relative_velocity as $object4)
            {
              if($i===1)
              {
                $output->writeln("kilometers_per_hour:".$object4);
                $neo->setSpeed($object4);
                $dm->persist($neo);
                $dm->flush();
              }
              $i=$i+1;
            }
          }


        }
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately, only the last object is saved.

I am using Robomongo to view it... and see only latest entry :(

Any ideas how to do it properly?

Also how can my code be optimized and improved for readability and performance?

Tahnks,

**Update 1:**

Changed my code to this, optimized it by removing one extra loop.

@Gerry:

Is this what you mean with creating Neo Object on each loop and than persisting it on loop end?

Can this code somehow be optimized? Made better readable?

Thanks,

```
$dm = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();


$jd = new JsonDecode();
$neo_obj = $jd->decode($response->getBody(),"json");
foreach($neo_obj->near_earth_objects as $date => $object1) {

    foreach($object1 as $object2)
    {
      $neo = new Neo();

      $output->writeln("Date:".$date);

      $neo->setDate($date);

      $output->writeln("Name:".$object2->name);

      $neo->setName($object2->name); 

      $output->writeln("neo_reference_id:".$object2->neo_reference_id);

      $neo->setNeoReferenceId($object2->neo_reference_id);

      $output->writeln("is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid:".$object2->is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid);

      $neo->setIsPotentiallyHazardousAsteroid($object2->is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid);

      foreach($object2->close_approach_data as $object3)
      {
        $i=0;
        foreach($object3->relative_velocity as $object4)
        {
          if($i===1)
          {
            $output->writeln("kilometers_per_hour:".$object4);
            $neo->setSpeed($object4);
            $dm->persist($neo);
            $dm->flush();
          }
          $i=$i+1;
        }
      }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persisting the same object several times has no effect, you only need to persist an object once and it will become "managed" by Doctrine.

In this code you are basically updating the same entity over and over again. If you want to batch create these objects, you need to call the constructor inside the iteration and call persist on every unique instance of your class.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question with Update 1 and new code based on your suggestion. It works now ... can it be done better? Following best practices or reading/performance optimizations?

Comment: You should limit a StackOverflow question to one question. Feel free to create a different question though regarding optimization and to accept this answer regarding your original question.